# "If I have done that" in the continuous form?

Tags: grammar, aspect

I saw this sentence on TV:

> 日々心によぎる「あのとき こうしていれば」という言葉。。。

and I wonder why していれば is used here and not すれば.

When I asked my teacher he said it is an N1 grammar point, he tried to explain it to me but I didn't get it.

I'm looking for more info on this to understand why it is like that, I didn't find it on a quick google search.

Here is one more example sentence that he gave me:

> あの時、ポケモンを見ていなかったら、日本語を勉強していなかったかもしれない。

Edit:
The suggested duplicate questions don't answer why it is like that, they just state that this is the right way.
I still don't know why they are using ていれば, if it is just like that - fine. But if there is a reason for a western mind to understand I will be glad to hear it.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25179/past-unreal-conditional

Comment: These questions doesn't answer why it is like that, it just states that this is the right way.
I still don't know why they are using ていれば, if it is just like that - fine. But if there is a reason for a western mind to understand I will be glad to hear it. @Chocolate

Comment: I think the explanation is in naruto’s answer here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40746/1478