# Can I say 「もしアイスクリームを食べたら、お腹が痛くなったでしょう。」 to mean the third conditional in Japanese

Tags: conditionals

So I know about the fact that Japanese doesn't have a literal equivalent to the third conditional of english.

But to say:

> If I had eaten ice cream, my stomach would have hurt.

Can I say it in japanese as:

> もしアイスクリームを食べたら、お腹が痛くなったでしょう。

And can I say "If I had come to Japan, I would have stayed in a hotel" as

> もし日本へ行ったら、ホテルに泊まりましたでしょう。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of conditional is usually translated using -ていれば or -ていたなら. The result part can be in either -ただろう/-たでしょう or -ていただろう/-ていたでしょう.

> If I had eaten ice cream, my stomach would have hurt.
> もしアイスクリームを食べていれば、お腹が痛くなっていただろう。
> もしアイスクリームを食べていたなら、お腹が痛くなっただろう。
>
> If I had come to Japan, I would have stayed in a hotel.
> もし日本へ行っていたなら、ホテルに泊まっていたでしょう。
> もし日本へ行っていれば、ホテルに泊まったでしょう。

[のに](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/64552/5010) is very commonly used with this type of conditional when the speaker is regretting. If the same person wanted to stay in a Japanese hotel for some reason but couldn't, the sentence would be:

> If I had come to Japan, I would have stayed in a hotel!
> もし日本へ行っていれば、ホテルに泊まったのに！

See also:

- [why they used -ていれば instead of -ば?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40745/5010)
- [～ば vs ～ていれば in counterfactual conditionals](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65029/5010)
- [Past Unreal Conditional](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25179/5010)

Lastly, don't use ましたでしょう. This duplication of polite forms is unnatural.

Comment: Why use たなら instead of たら? I've learned that you only use なら when it follows a noun and a na verb. Basically なら is equivalent to ば. https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/japanese-conditional-form-ba-nara.html

Comment: Also I've learned that using えば/なら has a regulation where the first sentence and the second sentence cannot have the same subject if the verb in the first sentence is an action verb. So why can ば and なら be used in the sentences above?  I learned that from the same link above.